# Losing small caps for serif font when merging mathpazo and sourcesanspro

Tags: fonts, small-caps, mathpazo, sourcesanspro

I use `mathpazo` font package to write my document. I use small caps for some text.

When I add `sourcesanspro` font package small caps don't work any more for *normal serif* font.

Here it is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum} % nopar
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
% COMMENT THIS LINE, COMPILE AGAIN AND SEE THE CHANGES :
\usepackage[light]{sourcesanspro}

\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex,hyperfootnotes=false,
             pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfadjustspacing=1 

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\textsc{\lipsum[3-4]}

\end{document}
```

When I comment `sourcesanspro` and compile the document, small caps are shown. When including `sourcesanspro`, small caps disappear. Why?? Have any of you already dealt with something similar?

My intention is to use `mathpazo` for mostly all the text in the document (serif), but replacing default sans-serif font by `sourcesanspro`. I don't know if I am doing something wrong, or if there is a better way to do that.

---

EDIT: I add more information.

When compiling without `sourcesanspro` I get 0 errors and 0 warning messages.

When compiling with `sourcesanspro`, I get 4 warning messages, and here they are:

> ```
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/ppl/l/n' undefined
> (Font)              using `T1/ppl/m/n' instead on input line 19.
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/ppl/l/sc' undefined
> (Font)              using `T1/ppl/l/n' instead on input line 22.
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/ppl/l/sl' undefined
> (Font)              using `T1/ppl/l/n' instead on input line 24.  
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
> ```

So, I think that the problem is that the option `light` that I use when calling `sourcesanspro` is affecting somehow also to the serif font.

Actually, if `light` option is removed, everything goes well, except for that the default sans-serif font won't be Source Sans Pro Light, of course.

---

POSSIBLE SOLUTION, if nothing better found:

One workaround that works for me is this:

- Removing the option `light` when including `sourcesanspro`.
- Adding this when the *light* version of that (sans serif) font is needed:

  ```
  \usefont{T1}{SourceSansPro-LF}{l}{n}
  ```

I learned about (or discovered) `SourceSansPro-LF` and things like that by reading into `sourcesanspro-type1.sty`. I think more documentation for `sourcesanspro` should be provided by the authors.

I leave this question opened (I mean, *unanswered*) because I would like to know if there is a way of avoiding typing `\usefont{T1}{SourceSansPro-LF}{l}{n}` every time I want to use the light sans-serif font provided by `sourcesanspro`.

Comment: I suggest a new tag for this post: `sourcesanspro`. I am not still allowed to create new tags.

Comment: @Vincent: Sorry you found the documentation lacking. I've been working on an updated version of the package with updated and [more complete documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nag1huqfvbwa84o/sourcesanspro.pdf). Let me know if you're missing something. I've also created a new tag as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the fact that the `light` option changes globally the meaning of `\mddefault` to `l` instead of the default `m` and so, when LaTeX wants to typeset in the Roman (Palatino) font, it has to perform some substitutions.

The substitution mechanism first tries to modify the shape, so the specification

```
ppl/l/sc
```

(Palatino Light Small Caps) turns into a request for

```
ppl/l/n
```

(Palatino Light Roman), which doesn't exist either, so the default substitution (`l` to `m`) is performed, resulting in Palatino Roman. You can solve the problem by defining new substitution rules:

```
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\normalfont % necessary to make LaTeX aware of our choice of the base font

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pplx}{l}{n} {<-> ssub * pplx/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pplx}{l}{sc}{<-> ssub * pplx/m/sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pplx}{l}{it}{<-> ssub * pplx/m/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pplx}{l}{sl}{<-> ssub * pplx/m/it}{}

\usepackage[light]{sourcesanspro}
```

Theoretically, the declaration could be delayed to `\AtBeginDocument`, but the package `sourcesanspro` loads also `fontaxes` that complicates the matter.

Note that I used the `sc` option to `mathpazo` so that a *real* small caps font is used instead of a fake one; this explains the usage of `pplx` instead of `ppl` as family name.

Comment: Thank you!! This solution is nicer than mine. And thank you also for the comment about `sc` option, that I forgot to use!